# Recommended coding style for setting property values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Let's say I have this interface:

```
// .h
@interface DataObject : NSObject {
    NSString* value;
}

@property (retain) NSString* value;

@end

// .m

@implementation DataObject

@synthetize value

@end
```

As far as I understand, the following two snippets are identical:

```
DataObject *o = [[[DataObject alloc] init] autorelease];
[o setValue: @"Hello"];

DataObject *o = [[[DataObject alloc] init] autorelease];
o.value = @"Hello";
```

Am I correct? If yes, should I prefer one over another one? Or is it just a style preference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a matter of style.

Dot syntax works in many places throughout Objective C, although it is only considered "acceptable" for getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the dot notation is preferable over calling the set method.  I think the code is more readable, and the dot notation more clearly identifies that you're setting a property, as opposed to just calling a method on the class.

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation is just syntactic sugar, so the two are identical.

Answer (score 0):

In August 2009, there was a brouhaha in the blogosphere regarding use of dot syntax.

- **Con**: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=83 (Joe Conway, who works for Big Nerd Ranch)
- **Pro**: http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=226 (Chris Hanson, who works for Apple)